# Cannot assign "'Test'": "BlogPostComment.blog_post" must be a "BlogPost" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to create an REST API for posting comments.
I am not using normal ```request.POST`` views as I don't want a new page redirect to submit a comment.

My plan is to AJAX to comment.

But I am getting this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/test/create_comment

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['blog',
 'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
 'rest_framework',
 'django_summernote',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\blog\views.py", line 44, in CreateComment
    serializer.create(request.data)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 939, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 451, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 485, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 215, in __set__
    raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /blog/test/create_comment
Exception Value: Cannot assign "'Test'": "BlogPostComment.blog_post" must be a "BlogPost" instance.
```

The console traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\blog\views.py", line 44, in CreateComment
    serializer.create(request.data)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 939, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 451, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 485, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "C:\My_Stuff\Blogistan\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 215, in __set__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "'Test'": "BlogPostComment.blog_post" must be a "BlogPost" instance.
```

My models:

```
class Author(User):
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=720)
    image = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name


class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=360, unique=True)
    urlpattern = models.SlugField(max_length=360, unique=True)
    content_html = TextField()
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class BlogPostComment(models.Model):
    blog_post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-time_added']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_post + ' | ' + self.user
```

My serializer:

```
class BlogPostCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    blog_post = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, queryset=BlogPost.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPostComment
        fields = ['blog_post', 'user', 'body']
        read_only_fields = []
```

My view:

```
def CreateComment(request, url):
    serializer = BlogPostCommentSerializer(read_only=False, data=request.data)
    
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.create(request.data)
    
    return Response(request.data)
```

I'am using sqlite3 now.
The hosted database was not doing its work properly.

Comment: Don't pass anything in `serializer.create`. Just use `serializer.create()` or just `serializer.save()`

Comment: Did your recommended change, it works well but now I get another error in my admin panel,

Comment: It says invalid operation for type BlogPostComment and str '+'. Sorry it is not copy pasted trace as I'm on my mobile

Comment: Ok when you can, try to post the whole traceback later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to solve the admin problem:

```
def __str__(self):
        return str(self.blog_post) + ' | ' + str(self.user)
```

I wasn't using `str()`.
I am unable to understand both are already strings then why was it giving this error

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a Blog Post model and "blog_post" must be a "BlogPost" instance not BlogPostComment.
Could you provide all models here?
The issue might be because of a relationship/connection between the two tables

Comment: I have added all of my models for your reference